# How to do Tornado HTTPServer with bind_unix_sock?

Tags: python, tornado, unix-socket, socat

I've got a simple server. It works if I do a normal socket, but if I try to use a unix socket, I don't think it's working.

Here is the server:

```
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
import tornado.ioloop
from tornado.netutil import bind_unix_socket
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = HTTPServer(application)
    unix_socket = bind_unix_socket('/tmp/foo.sock')
    server.add_socket(unix_socket)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Here is how I'm testing:

```
~  socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/foo.sock
GET / HTTP/1.1
HOST: foobar.com
*hit enter a few times to complete http call*
```

The server doesn't give any response.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending \n instead of \r\n.  You can use socat's "crnl" option to make it work more like telnet:

```
socat - unix-connect:/tmp/foo.sock,crnl
```

Comment: this command is not giving any output (idle) with the above (OP) server. Can you please help in saying what is happening. I am using Python3.5.2 with tornado==5.1.1 on ubuntu 16.04.